# Adding background color to element within php if-statement

Tags: php, html, css, json, if-statement

I have the following code in which I want to add an element to my if statement, but I am unsure how to approach this. What I am looking to do is add a background-color to the else part of it. Within this:

```
else {
        $status_img = '<img src="../icons/collection/checkmark.png" alt="Goal Complete">';
}
```

So if `$status` is not 0, I want to set background color for the class `goal-box-right`.

Is there anyway I can manipulate the CSS through php like this?

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $status = $row['status'];
            if ($status == 0) {
                $status_img = '<img src="../icons/collection/x-sign.png" alt="Goal Not Complete">';
            }
            else {
                $status_img = '<img src="../icons/collection/checkmark.png" alt="Goal Complete">';
            }
            $goal_date = $row['date'];
            $fixed_goal_date = fixDate($goal_date);
            $html = "";
            $html .= '<div class="goal-box" id="comment-'.$row['id'].'">';
            $html .= '<div class="goal-box-left">'; //added
            $html .= '<div class="goal-post-status">'.$status_img. '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>'; //added
            $html .= '<div class="goal-box-right">'; //added
            $html .= '<div class="goal-post-title">'.$row['title']. '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="goal-post-date">'.$fixed_goal_date. '</div>';
            $html .= '<div class="goal-post-description">'.$row['description']. '</div>';
            $html .= '</div>'; //added
            $html .= '</div>';
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: Why don't you set the background-color as an inline style?

Comment: The problem is I do not know how to set the background color to a different color through my if statement.

Comment: You use an additional css class polling a specific background color each. That way you can easily switch by php, you simply assign different classes to the element. That prevents that you have to use dynamic css which would make the css non-cachable.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for the other tip regarding the one answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate the logic - add a CSS class based on the status then set the colours in the stylesheet.

```
$class = $status != 0 ? 'status-nonzero' : '';

$html .= '<div class="goal-box-right ' . $class . '">';
```

CSS:

```
.goal-box-right.status-nonzero { background-color: #foo }
```

Advantage is keeping the style logic in the CSS where it belongs and away from the code that's generating the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for this method. I used this and it works great. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

So what's the problem:

```
$style = '';
if ($status == 0) {
    $style = ' style="your-style:here"';
    $status_img = '<img src="../icons/collection/x-sign.png" alt="Goal Not Complete">';
}
else {
    $status_img = '<img src="../icons/collection/checkmark.png" alt="Goal Complete">';
}

// ...
$html .= '<div class="goal-box-right"' . $style . '>'; //added
```

Comment: Worked great. Thanks.